# Eigenvalues of an endomorphism over a polynomial ring

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, polynomial-rings

I am currently preparing for a math exam and am stuck on the following question:

> Let $\Bbb K$ be a field, let $\Bbb K[T]$ be the polynomial ring over the variable $T$ over $\Bbb K$, and let $\phi : \Bbb K[T]  \rightarrow \Bbb K[T]$ be the $\Bbb K$-linear endomorphism given by $f \mapsto (T+1)\cdot f$. Determine all eigenvalues for $ \phi $.

I think there shouldn’t be any eigenvalues. My reason being: Let $ \lambda $ be an eigenvalue for $ \phi $ and g a corresponding eigenvector. Then, $ (T + 1) \cdot g = \lambda \cdot g \leftrightarrow (T + 1 - \lambda) \cdot g = 0 $ must hold. However, this is contradictory to the fact that $\Bbb K[T]$ is an integral domain (since $\Bbb K$ is an integral domain) and (T + 1 - $ \lambda $) and g are unequal to 0.

Could you tell me if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: Also, please tell me if any terms are unclear (I am a German speaking student, the question was originally formulated in German and I don't know for sure the correct English mathematical terms)

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that $\phi(f) = (T+1) \cdot f$?

Comment: @Riquelme that's given in the question

Comment: @DeapSoup If I understood everything correctly, your reasoning and conclusion are completely correct.

Comment: Oh, the $\cdot f $ was in the next line^^

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! Do I need anything to 'close' the question or anything similar? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my reasoning is indeed correct, according to Omnomnomnom.

Comment: Sure let $Af = (T+1) f$ then $(A-\lambda I)f = (T+1-\lambda) f$ so $\ker(A-\lambda I)=\{0\}$